# Execute Selenium script from CGI script

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I am currently working on a project where we need to run a Selenium Script to automate some processes on an IE browser. We have to do this via Selenium as the website we're run automation on doesn't have an API and ONLY works on an old version of IE, due to certificates.

Thus, I've come up with the following solution:

1. Create CGI script on EC2 Windows server that contains Selenium code
2. Parse parameters from the URL to this script, which are then entered into the Selenium fields.
3. Connect externally every time this Selenium script needs to be run.

I've created the EC2 server, I've allowed for CGI scripts and this works fine with a basic CGI script. As soon as I add the following lines the browser just hangs and does nothing:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie("C:/IEDriverServer.exe")
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Does anyone have experience doing something similar, when the browser hangs, the Selenium script executes an IE server background process, but doesn't actually launch IE.

```
#!C://Python27/python.exe

from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
print('Hello,s world!')




# Setup default variables
browser = webdriver.Ie("C:/IEDriverServer.exe")
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Are you using a version of the IE driver that is compatible with the version of IE installed on your EC2 server?

Comment: Good question, how would I go about checking? @BreaksSoftware

Comment: I've managed to check and yes they are correct. @BreaksSoftware